# Changed mysql to mysqli and can't connect to database

Tags: mysqli

I am not very experienced in this field so this is why I am seeking help.

I recently changed hosts and a script stopped working. After moving all files the new hosts said mysql is deprecated, so after doing a bit of search I decided to change mysql with mysqli and that deprecated error was gone. But now I get a new error (error select db). I think I must make adidtional changes to the script to connect mysqli. This is the file I have

```html
<?php

class Model{
 var $conn;
 
 public function openDb($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname, $conn) 
 {
  //echo "Se creo la conexion ";
  $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Error connecting to mysqli');
  mysqli_select_db($dbname) or die('Error select db');
  mysqli_query("SET NAMES utf8");
  return $conn;
 }

 public function closeDb($conn) 
 {
  mysqli_close($conn);
 }

 public function query($query) 
 {
  if ($result = mysqli_query($query) or die("Error de Query: </br >" . mysqli_error()."<br/>".$query)) {
  //if ($result = mysqli_query($query)) {
  } else {
   $result = false;
  }
  return $result;
 }
 
 function __construct()
 {
  $this->openDb(dbhost, dbuser, dbpass, dbname, $conn);
 }
 
  //insertGenerico con indedices asiciativos
    function insertar($tabla, $datos) 
    {
        $columnas = implode(", ", array_keys($datos));
        $valores = implode(", ", $datos);
        $query = "INSERT INTO $tabla
        ($columnas)
        VALUES
        (" . $valores . ")";
        return $this -> query($query);
    }

    function insertarRelacionArray($tabla, $tablaRelacion, $datos) 
    {
        foreach ($datos as $row) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO $tabla
            ($tablaRelacion[0],$tablaRelacion[2])
            VALUES
            ($tablaRelacion[1],$row)";
            //echo '<br>'.$query;
            $this -> query($query);
        }
    }

    //getGenerico
    function get($tabla, $where = false, $order = false) 
    {
        $query = "SELECT *
        FROM $tabla
        $where
        $order";
        return $this -> query($query);
    }

    //deleteGenerico
    function delete($tabla, $id, $idTag = false) 
    {
     if($idTag==false)
            $idTag = "id";
        $query = "DELETE FROM $tabla
        WHERE $idTag = $id";
        return $this -> query($query);
    }

    //update generico
    function update($tabla, $datos, $id, $idTag = false) 
    {
        $columnas = array_keys($datos);
        $SET = 'SET ';
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($datos as $key => $value) {
            if (next($datos)) {
                $SET .= "$key = $value ,";
            } else {
                $SET .= "$key = $value ";
            }
        }
        if($idTag==false)
            $idTag = "id";
        $query = "UPDATE $tabla $SET WHERE $idTag = $id;";
        return $this -> query($query);
    }

 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As described on http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php first parameter should be $link.

```
bool mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname )
```

So change

```
mysqli_select_db($dbname) or die('Error select db');
```

to

```
mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname) or die('Error select db');
```

and it should work.
I think that you need to return $conn in your _construct function too, or store it in the object ($this->conn = $conn) so you can use it again.

In addition (thanks to Ki Jéy) you should also update

```
mysql_query($query)
to
mysqli_query($conn, $query)
```

and

```
mysql_real_escape_string($string)
to
mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $string)
```

Comment: I would add as complementary info since I have done the exact same operation for the exact same reasons (changing all my code from mysql to mysqli because it was deprecated) that every call to `mysql_query()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()` have to be updated to match the new prototype (as described in php.net)